# Velocity email template in /WEB-INF subfolder

Tags: spring, velocity, email

I coded service to send email. Now I have to integrate velocity freamwork and so I edit my mail-context.xml

```
....
<bean id="mailService" class="xxx.xxxx.xxxx.service.MailServiceImpl">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
        <property name="simpleMailMessage" ref="customeMailMessage" />
        <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="velocityEngine"
        class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="resource.loader">webapp</prop>
                <prop key="webapp.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader</prop>
                <prop key="webapp.resource.loader.path">/WEB-INF/email</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
...
```

And I put in /WEB-INF/email my template file .vm
This is my mail service

```
@Service("MailService")
@Transactional
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {


    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

    private SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage;

    public void setSimpleMailMessage(SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage) {
        this.simpleMailMessage = simpleMailMessage;
    }

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void setVelocityEngine(VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
        this.velocityEngine = velocityEngine;
    }
.....
public void sendEmailVelocity(final Userprofile userprofile) throws MessagingException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Sending mail...");

        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        Map model = new HashMap();
        model.put("user", userprofile);
        helper.setFrom("info@spidly.com");
        helper.setTo("claudio.pomo@gmail.com");
        helper.setSubject("velocity");

        String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "test.vm", model);
        helper.setText(text, true);
        mailSender.send(message);
        System.out.println("Mail sent!");
    }

...
```

And then the stack trace is

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'test.vm'
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:343)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:320)
    at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngineUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(VelocityEngineUtils.java:122)
    at xx.xxxxxxx.xxx.service.MailServiceImpl.sendEmailVelocity(MailServiceImpl.java:410)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy61.sendEmailVelocity(Unknown Source)org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'test.vm'
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:343)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:320)
    at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngineUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(VelocityEngineUtils.java:122)
    at xx.xxxxx.xxxx.service.MailServiceImpl.sendEmailVelocity(MailServiceImpl.java:410)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy61.sendEmailVelocity(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `velocityEngine` bean to

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/email/" />
</bean>
```

and it should work.

Comment: And you're sure the template `/WEB-INF/email/test.vm` exists?

Comment: Sure! I write this and put into /WEB-INF/email folder.

Comment: Your resource path most be off somehow. Do you have some other resource loader configured? I wrote a test https://gist.github.com/onedott/5539747 which works as expected. Only difference is that the test uses the classpath.

Comment: That explains everything :-) For testing purposes just store the templates on the classpath. Or if you're using maven put it in `test/resources`.